# Pyspark get rows with max value for a column over a window

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, group-by, window

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
| created        | id   | date       |value|
| 1650983874871  | x    | 2020-05-08 | 5   |
| 1650367659030  | x    | 2020-05-08 | 3   |
| 1639429213087  | x    | 2020-05-08 | 2   |
| 1650983874871  | x    | 2020-06-08 | 5   |
| 1650367659030  | x    | 2020-06-08 | 3   |
| 1639429213087  | x    | 2020-06-08 | 2   |
```

I want to get max of created for every date.
The table should look like :

```
    | created        | id   | date       |value|
    | 1650983874871  | x    | 2020-05-08 | 5   |
    | 1650983874871  | x    | 2020-06-08 | 5   |
```

I tried:

```
df2 = (
        df
        .groupby(['id', 'date'])
        .agg(
            F.max(F.col('created')).alias('created_max')
            
        )
df3 = df.join(df2, on=['id', 'date'], how='left')
```

But this is not working as expected.
Can anyone help me.

Comment: no. I still want the max timestamp at created. so even if there is 6 a any smaller timestamp it deosnt matter. 
Basically I want to get latest(max) created records.

Comment: what you've done seems correct. what does your approach output?

Comment: also, why are the values in `value` field only 5 for all records of the required output? is it taking a max of the `value` field as well?

Comment: The way I am getting it is just an extra column with created_max value.
Also the values are co incidentally max when created is max.

Comment: i think all you want to do is apply a `filter(func.col('created')==func.col('created_max'))` after the join

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the group by and joining, you can also use the `Window` in `pyspark.sql`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = df\
     .withColumn('max_created', func.max('created').over(Window.partitionBy('date', 'id')))\
     .filter(func.col('created')==func.col('max_created'))\
     .drop('max_created')
```

Step:

1. Get the max value based on the Window
2. Filter the row by using the matched timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes.

1. The join condition needs to include `created` as well. Here I have changed alias to `alias("created")` to make the join easier. This will ensure a unique join condition (if there are no duplicate `created` values).
2. The join type must be `inner`.

```py
df2 = (
        df
        .groupby(['id', 'date'])
        .agg(
            F.max(F.col('created')).alias('created')
        )
)
df3 = df.join(df2, on=['id', 'date','created'], how='inner')

df3.show()

+---+----------+-------------+-----+
| id|      date|      created|value|
+---+----------+-------------+-----+
|  x|2020-05-08|1650983874871|    5|
|  x|2020-06-08|1650983874871|    5|
+---+----------+-------------+-----+
```